# Spring Boot Rest Controller API not returning value in json Format

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

**Problem Description**

In spring Boot API data come in JSON format but for me data populating in below format.

**Data Format**

table attribute is missing which help to bind data in drop down list
    ["TETE","ZZZZ","XXXX","AAAA","BBBB"]

**Requirement**

Using Angularjs creating a drop down list.

---

## Spring Boot Code

### Repository

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<xCategory,Integer>
{
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT a.categoryName FROM xCategory a order by categoryName asc")
    List<String> getCategoryName();
}
```

### Controller

```
@GetMapping("/getAllCategory")
public List<String> getAllCategory() {              
    List<String> cCategory = categoryRepository.getCategoryName(); 
    return cCategory;
}
```

### Angular Code

```
<label class="control-label">Category: </label>
<select  [(ngModel)]="listAllCategory" name="xcategory" class="form-control" required>
    <option *ngFor="let xcategory of listAllCategory" [value]="xcategory.catID">
        {{xcategory.categoryName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you maybe use the `@Controller` annotation instead of `@RestController`?

Comment: Thanks Matthias! But this solution is NOT working for me.